Openapi-Generator does not set configuration parameters in angular
We are working on a project with a Angular 17.3 Frontend and a spring Backend. Our API is defined in an OpenApi-yaml and generated by openapi-generator ("@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^2.13.1"). This has worked totally fine until we implemented our security: we are using http sessions. The cookie which contains the session-id is send correctly when you log in, but it doesn't get send back when the program sends a request to the backend. We figured out that it needs to have something to do with the generation of the api, because when we set the configuration parameter in the generated code to {withCredentials: true}, then it works. The thing is, that we can't find out how to set that in configuration. We generate our api with a js script and pass a configuration file in the generator command, but it doesn't seem to work, because our generated configuration still has no parameters. Can anybody help us solving that issue?
This is our Code:
swagger_generate.js:
const exec = require('child_process').execSync;
const fs = require('fs-extra');

async function clean(path) {
  return fs.remove(path);
}

function generate(path, yaml, swaggerConfig) {
  const generateCall = 'openapi-generator-cli generate -i ' + yaml + ' -g typescript-angular -o ' + path + ' -c ' + swaggerConfig;
  console.log('Executing command:', generateCall);
  exec(generateCall, {stdio: 'inherit'});
}

async function refreshInterface({apiPath, yaml, swaggerConfig}) {
  await clean(apiPath);
  return new Promise(() => {
    generate(apiPath, yaml, swaggerConfig);
  });
}

function main() {
  const restInterfaces = [
    {
      apiPath: 'src/rest/generated/maishai/clipping/',
      yaml: 'openapi/swagger/clipping-swagger.yml',
      swaggerConfig: 'openapi/swagger-nodegen-config.json'
    },
    {
      apiPath: 'src/rest/generated/maishai/observation/',
      yaml: 'openapi/swagger/observation-swagger.yml',
      swaggerConfig: 'openapi/swagger-nodegen-config.json'
    },
    {
      apiPath: 'src/rest/generated/maishai/organization/',
      yaml: 'openapi/swagger/organization-swagger.yml',
      swaggerConfig: 'openapi/swagger-nodegen-config.json'
    },
    {
      apiPath: 'src/rest/generated/maishai/user/',
      yaml: 'openapi/swagger/user-swagger.yml',
      swaggerConfig: 'openapi/swagger-nodegen-config.json'
    }
  ];

  Promise.all(restInterfaces.map
    (config => {
        return refreshInterface(config);
      }
    )
  )
    .catch(err => console.error('Unexpected error in swagger code gen' + JSON.stringify(err)));
}


main();

openapi/swagger-nodegen-config.json:
{
  "modelPropertyNaming": "original",
  "supportsES6" :true,
  "ngVersion": "17.3.1",
  "npmName": "restClient",
  "withInterfaces": true,
  "withCredentials": true
}

package.json:
...
    "swagger:generate": "node openapi/swagger_generate.js"

...
Code generated based on that:
clipping.service.ts:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClippingService implements ClippingServiceInterface {

    protected basePath = 'http://localhost:4200/api/v1';
    public defaultHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    public configuration = new Configuration();
    public encoder: HttpParameterCodec;

...
configuration.ts
export class Configuration {
    /**
     *  @deprecated Since 5.0. Use credentials instead
     */
    apiKeys?: {[ key: string ]: string};
    username?: string;
    password?: string;
    /**
     *  @deprecated Since 5.0. Use credentials instead
     */
    accessToken?: string | (() => string);
    basePath?: string;
    withCredentials?: boolean;
    encoder?: HttpParameterCodec;
    /**
     * The keys are the names in the securitySchemes section of the OpenAPI
     * document. They should map to the value used for authentication
     * minus any standard prefixes such as 'Basic' or 'Bearer'.
     */
    credentials: {[ key: string ]: string | (() => string | undefined)};

    constructor(configurationParameters: ConfigurationParameters = {}) {
        this.apiKeys = configurationParameters.apiKeys;
        this.username = configurationParameters.username;
        this.password = configurationParameters.password;
        this.accessToken = configurationParameters.accessToken;
        this.basePath = configurationParameters.basePath;
        this.withCredentials = configurationParameters.withCredentials;
        this.encoder = configurationParameters.encoder;
        if (configurationParameters.credentials) {
            this.credentials = configurationParameters.credentials;
        }
        else {
            this.credentials = {};
        }
    }

...
As you see, new Configuration(); has no parameters although it should have.
Thank you for your help :)
I tried to change the generate function in swagger_generate.js to:
function generate(path, yaml, swaggerConfig) {
  const generateCall = 'openapi-generator-cli generate -i ' + yaml + ' -g typescript-angular -o ' + path + ' --additional-properties withCredentials=true --generate-alias-as-model';
  console.log('Executing command:', generateCall);
  exec(generateCall, {stdio: 'inherit'});
}

but that didn't change anything.
